# When is context.Result null inside of an action filter .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I noticed in ASP.NET Core MVC `ModelStateInvalidFilter` checks if `Context.Result == null` before checking `ModelState.IsValid`? What's the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in the `Result` property description comment in the [ActionExecutingContext.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Abstractions/src/Filters/ActionExecutingContext.cs):

> Gets or sets the `IActionResult` to execute. Setting `Result` to a
> **non-null** value inside an action filter will short-circuit the action
> and any remaining action filters.

This means if the short-circuit of the action already initiated there is no reason to overwrite the previous value in case the `context.ModelState.IsValid` set to `false`. It would be wrong approach.

Comment: Ah okay, makes sense. You wouldn't want to modify a previous action if it was already set.